# Laravel route not working in Apache using custom port in virtual host

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, laravel, virtualhost, selinux

I have a server running Linux. Its a VM with ip `10.61.0.3`. Currently used to serve my web located at `/var/www/html` at port `80`.

I want to serve Laravel app from this server located at `/var/www/laraapp` to port `8080`.

My current apache conf for virtual host is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName 10.61.0.3:8080
  DocumentRoot /var/www/laraapp/public
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access `10.61.0.3:8080` nothing is shown up. Here is what show on apache error_logs:

```
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:43 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:48 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:48 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:48 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:48 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:48 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 17 17:28:48 2014] [error] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("10.61.0.3") failed: Invalid host name
```

What should I do?

Note:

- I can run my larapp using builtin PHP web server.
- `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
- `Listen 8080` already declared in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

In Apache documentation, `ServerName` should something like domain name http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername

Try to change `ServerName 10.61.0.3` to `ServerName example.com`.

Don't forget to add `127.0.0.1 example.com` into your `/etc/hosts`.

If you want VirtualHost runnning on port 8080, you must define `NameVirtualHost` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#port

For example:

```
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 10.61.0.3:8080

<VirtualHost 10.61.0.3:8080>
    ServerName example.com  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laraapp/public  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you changed the file in System32?